# how to sort data at the time of adding it, not later?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, data-structures

I am new to algorithms so please forgive me if this sounds basic or stupid.

I want to know this : instead of adding data into some kind of list and then performing a sort on the list, is there a method (data structure+algorithm) that lets me sort the data at the time of adding itself, or to put it another way, inserts the data in its proper place?

eg: if I want to add '3' to {1,5,6}, instead of adding it at the start or end and then sorting the list, I want '3' to go after '1' "directly".

thanks

Answer (score 8):

If you use a binary search tree instead of an array, the sorting would happen "automatically", because it's already done by the insert method of the nodes. So a binary tree is always sorted, and it's easy to traverse. The only problem is that when you have already (more or less) sorted data, the tree becomes inbalanced (which is where red-black-trees and other variations come into play).

Answer (score 1):

You want to maintain a sorted array at all times, so you shall find a correct place in sequence for every new element you want to add to the array. This can be done efficiently (`O(logn)` complexity) by utilizing a modified [binary search algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm).

Comment: Finding the right position in the array can be found in O(log n) time - but inserting into an array requires O(n) time.

Comment: That's correct. This might compel to do both steps at once, in a very similar manner to inner loop in InsertionSort algorithm. However, if one additionally wants to preserve uniqueness of elements in collection, using binary search could be preferred as it still has `O(logn)` when attempting to insert a duplicate.

Comment: If you have a sizable collection, binary search is **never** preferred over something like a BTree.  It is easy to find pre-rolled implementations of BTrees in most languages.

Comment: A single continuous block of memory is much more cache-friendly than a multitude of nodes scattered over whole address space - and that what BTree is in many implementations.

Comment: @btilly Not BTrees - BTrees are n-ary trees designed specifically for disk storage.

Comment: @Xion: Look again, the first several nodes of a BTree is more likely to be in cache than the first X places a binary search looks in a large file.  A well-designed BTree is much, much friendlier to caches.  For an extreme example see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/devdev/archive/2007/06/12/cache-oblivious-data-structures.aspx.

Comment: @nick-johnson: BTrees are widely used for that, but can be appropriate for other cases with multiple levels of data that can be accessed different speeds.  Which can happen inside of CPU caches.  Regardless, even if something better exists for a particular use case, they are still better for sizable collections than a sorted list that you do binary search on.

Comment: Hey everyone: BTree is just a generalisation of binary tree. Tweak the BTree parameters just so and you get a binary tree. Tweak them some other way and you get the solution that's right for your system.

Answer (score 0):

There are basically two different methods to insert a value in a list, which you use depend a bit on what kind of list you are using:

- Use binary search to locate where the value should be inserted, and insert the value there.
- Loop from the end of the list, moving all higher values one step up, and put the value in the gap before the lowest higher value.

The first method would typically be used if you are using a binary tree or a linked list, where you don't have to move items in the list to do the insert.

Answer (score 0):

Yes but that's usually slower than adding all the data and sorting it afterwards because to insert the data as it is added, you need to traverse the list every time you add an element.

With binary search, you need not look at every element but even then, you often need to get more elements from the list as when you sort afterwards.

So from a performance view, sorted insert is inferior to post sorting.

Comment: Unless you need the data to _always_ be in sorted order.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a golang code that sorts inputs on the fly

What I am doing here is that I am determining the position of where possibly the input will fit through binary search and then partitioning the already sorted array to fit the element, appending to part one and then rejoining the two parts.

time complexity = Log N(to determine the position) + 3N (to create slices and append for each input)

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    var a []int
    for {
        fmt.Print("Please enter a value:")
        text := readLine(reader)
        key, _ := strconv.ParseInt(text, 10, 0)
        pos := binarySearch(a, 0, len(a)-1, int(key))
        p1 := append([]int{}, a[:pos]...)
        p2 := a[pos:]
        p1 = append(p1, int(key))
        p1 = append(p1, p2...)
        a = p1
        fmt.Println(a)
    }
}

func binarySearch(a []int, low int, high int, key int) int {
    var result int
    if high == -1 {
        return 0
    } else if key >= a[high] {
        return high + 1
    } else if key <= a[low] {
        return low
    }
    mid := (high + low) / 2
    if a[mid] == key {
        result = mid
    } else if key < a[mid] {
        return binarySearch(a, low, mid-1, key)
    } else if key > a[mid] {
        return binarySearch(a, mid+1, high, key)
    }
    return result
}

func readLine(reader *bufio.Reader) string {
    text, err := reader.ReadString('\n')
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    text = strings.TrimRight(text, "\n")
    return text
}
```