# Most efficient method to sort on the fly

Tags: c, sorting, data-structures

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to sort data at the time of adding it, not later?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5831558/how-to-sort-data-at-the-time-of-adding-it-not-later)

I need to sort data on the fly. Basically I have an array in which elements will be inserted. After each insert, the data should be sorted. What is fastest way to achieve that?

Comment: Depending on the data you are trying to sort there may be different approaches. So what are you trying to sort?

Comment: After each insert of one element, or of multiple elements?

Comment: The other question is what do you *want* with the data? what is the access pattern: do you only want to be able to "index" them by rank? Should *deletes* be allowed, or even *updates*?

Answer (score 7):

The fastest way to achieve this is to drop the array and use a binary search tree instead for O(lg *n*) sorted insertion. With an array, you'll always be stuck with linear-time insertion due to the need to shift *n*/2 of the elements on average.

**EDIT**: you can also use a [heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_%28data_structure%29) instead of a BST; that can be implemented in terms of an array. However, iteration would take O(*n* lg *n*) for a binary heap, while in a [threaded BST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Threaded_binary_tree) it can be done in O(*n*) time with O(1) extra memory.

Comment: This may be true in general, but in particular cases better performance can be achieved. For example when the input consists of limited integer values you can use [bucket-sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bucket_sort)

Comment: I agree; an intrinsically sorted structure (either sort-on-insert like a B-tree,etc. or sort-on-iterate, can't think of an example) has to be the way to go.

Comment: @MattyK: sort on iterate can be achieved with a heap.

Answer (score 0):

If after each insertion the array is sorted, then the fastest way to do this would be to use a binary search algorithm to find where the element should be inserted, and shift all the elements starting at that position and going right down one, and insert the element into the gap you created.

That said, it would really be better to use a BST if you can, as larsmans said. That way you can avoid having to move potentially all the elements each time one is inserted.

Comment: The first paragraph is what I was also thinking :-).