# What's the most efficient way to construct a new, sorted, array?

Tags: arrays, sorting

### Background

Most questions around sorting talk about sorting an existing unsorted array. Is constructing a new array in a sorted order an equivalent problem or a different one? Here's an example that will clear things up:

### Example

I'm generating `N` random numbers and want to insert them into a new array as I generate them, and I want the final array to be sorted.

### Possible Solutions

#### Insertion Sort

My gut told me that putting each element in the correct place as it's generated would be fastest. This is accomplished by doing a binary search to find the correct point in the array to insert the new element. However, this is an insertion sort, which is known to be less efficient on large lists than other sorting algorithms.

#### Quicksort

Quicksort is generally thought of as the most efficient 'general' sorting algorithm, where nothing is known about the inputs to the array, and it's more efficient than insertion sort on large lists. Would it, therefore, be best to simply put the random numbers in the array in an unsorted order, and then sort them at the end with quicksort?

### Other Solutions

Is there another algorithm I haven't thought of?

Comment: Depends on your numbers, like type and distribution. And also the programming language.

Comment: I'm looking for a general, language-agnostic answer, that works for a random dataset of unknown distribution.

Comment: As for the most efficient data structure, a self-balancing binary search tree is a very good option.

Comment: *"However, this is an insertion sort, which is known to be less efficient on large lists than other sorting algorithms."*
No it is not insertion sort. Some inefficiency comes from the need to shift the array elements to make room for the new element, but you don't *swap*  elements as you would in the insertion sort.

Comment: @jrook Does a self-balancing binary search tree stand a chance here? I'd think its strength is as a dynamic data structure, not as being used once to produce a sorted array. It has a lot of overhead work and data to hold and update the tree structure, and it still won't be as perfectly balanced as let's say a mergesort (and I guess less cache-friendly, too).

Comment: @superbrain Yes, for example, Java's `TreeSet` uses a red black tree under the hood to grow a sorted collection. I don't understand your reference to merge sort. Merge sort depends on subarrays to be already sorted. It is no good if we want to sort on the fly or I am missing something.

Comment: @jrook Merge depends on sorted subarrays. Mergesort recursively sorts them before merging. Not sure what your point with Java's `TreeSet` is. But I suspect putting the values into a `TreeSet` and then moving them into an array is significantly slower than putting the values into an array and then sorting that. Even without the move-to-array part, just the `TreeSet` building alone.

Comment: @superbrain You can always wait until you have full array and then use *any* performant sorting algorithm which will be nlogn complexity (or even O(n) for non-comparison sorts). To keep a growing sorted array though, I don't think you can do much better than a self balancing BST. Copying to a result array will be O(n) which is justified.

Comment: @jrook "keep a growing sorted array" doesn't sound like what the question sounds like to me. At least in the example he explicitly says "want the *final* array to be sorted".

Comment: @superbrain Assuming a comparison based sorting, one can't do better than nlogn (self-balancing BST). Any other game you play during number generation will just add some overhead, possibly more than BST.

Comment: @jrook Not sure what you're measuring with "nlogn" and what logarithm base you mean, but different solutions of the same complexity class can still differ by a large constant factor. And I think self-balancing BST is a rather slow one.

Comment: @superbrain I don't necessarily disagree. I am just curious to see how mergesort or quicksort are good *if we use them on the fly*. For example, how would one avoid shifting large chunks of elements?
If we are going to wait until the array is built, then the whole discussion is moot. Use any nlogn sorting algorithm and you're good.

Comment: @jrook I think you're the only one talking about using them "on the fly", and I don't understand why you're doing it.

Comment: @superbrain from the question: "Is **constructing a new array in a sorted order** an equivalent problem or a different one?" and 
"I'm generating N random numbers and want to insert them into a new array **as I generate them**."

Comment: Note that if the question devolves into: "which sorting algorithm is better?" , then it should be closed for being too broad. In that case, the answer would be "it depends", not "mergesort", "quicksort" or "whatever sort"

Comment: @jrook Your latter quote conveniently cuts off the sentence right before the part that I quoted, which says he wants the **final** array to be sorted. And your first quote doesn't imply on-the-fly, either.

Comment: @AdamGriffiths Is there a specific use case you are ultimately trying to achieve here or is this more of a conceptual question?

Do you have a hard requirement that the sorted data (as you generated and insert them) is stored specifically in a single array structure and not any alternative data structure (e.g. allocating and reusing the same `Object[]` in Java, `[]` in JavaScript/Python)? And further - while you are inserting new entries in sorted order, the allocated array is allowed to have unused entries trailing after the filled entries?

Comment: @concision This is a conceptual question, it came up in an algorithms interview and there I used the 'insertion sort' style approach, but I'm not sure it's the correct approach. The solution can use any data structure (Java ArrayLists for example), but it should not have unused entries trailing after the filled entries.

Comment: @jrook rain: superb rain is correct. I want the **final array** to be sorted, I don't care if it's sorted as I populate the data. If the most efficient answer is "dump all the data in an unsorted order and the use quicksort" then fine, but I suspect it's more efficient to sort the array as the data comes in.

Comment: @AdamGriffiths It *can't* be more efficient than O(nlogn) (for comparison-based sort) or you could just read any array's elements one by one and sort them more efficiently. 
Your idea of binary search to find the right place for each new elment works except that you will pay a very high price for shifting elements to make room, thus my suggestion for a self-balancing BST. That's what Java does under the hood for `TreeSet`.

Comment: @AdamGriffiths Also, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8489865/2928853)

Comment: I think in the case of "insert as you go, but we do not know how many entries there will be", a self-balancing BST (as jrook has repeatedly suggested) is close to ideal due to `O(log n)` insertion time for a total of `O(n log n)` time complexity for sorting all the data. However, if we sort _after_ generating all `N` entries, I suspect this truly does turn into "which sort algorithm is the fastest?" (also as jrook suggested) and the answer is: ***it depends***. Sorting afterwards with a comparison sort will yield, at best, `O(n log n)` (e.g. heap sort, also self balancing BST).

Answer (score 6):

> Most questions around sorting talk about sorting an existing unsorted array. Is constructing a new array in a sorted order an equivalent problem or a different one?

It boils down to the same problem for *random data*, due to efficiency considerations.

Given *random data*, it's actually more efficient to first generate the random values into an array (unsorted) - *O(n)* time complexity - and then sort it with your favorite *O(n log n)* sort algorithm, making the entire operation *O(2n log n)* time complexity, and, depending on sort algorithm used, between *O(1)* and *O(n)* space complexity.

There is no way to beat that approach by "keeping an array sorted as it's constructed" for *random data*, because any approach will require exactly *O(n)* generations/insertions of the values, and *at least O(n log n) comparisons/swaps/shifts* - no matter which method, from the numerous mentioned in comments on the original question, is used. Note, as per a very useful comment on my original answer, the  *binary insertion sort* variant suggested in the original question will likely degrade to *O(n^2)* time complexity, making it an inferior solution to just generating an array of values first and then sorting it.

Using a balanced tree just *matches the time complexity* of generating an array and then sorting it - but *loses in space complexity*, as trees have some overhead, compared to an array, to keep track of child nodes, etc. Also of note, trees are heap-allocated, and require a pointer dereference operation for accessing any child node - so even though the Big-O time complexity is equivalent to first generating an  array of data and then sorting it, the *real performance* of the tree solution will be worse, as there's no data locality, and there's extra cost of pointer dereference. An additional consideration on balanced trees is that insertion cost into something like an AVL is quite high - that is, the *n* in AVL's *O(n log n)* insertion is not the same cost as *n* in an in-place sort of an array, due to necessary rotations of tree nodes to achieve balance. Just because Big-O is the same doesn't mean performance is the same. Even if you have an *absolute need* to be able to grab the data in a sorted order *at some point during construction of the array*, it might still be cheaper to just sort an array as you need it, unless you need it sorted at each insertion!

Note, this answer pertains to *random data* - it is possible, and even likely, to come up with a more efficient approach for "keeping an array sorted as it's constructed" if both the size and characteristics of the data are known, and follow some mathematical pattern, other than randomness; however, such approach would necessarily be overfit for the specific data set it relates to, rather than a general solution.

Comment: A note here that keeping the array sorted "as it's constructed" (where **i.** all elements in the array are guaranteed sorteded at every step and **ii**. unused array positions trail _after_ all used array positions) with a binary insertion sort *will* require shifting array elements, which can be `O(n/2)` on average and `O(n)` worst case. The time-complexity will ultimately end up in `O(n^2)` territory since it is an`O(n)` operation repeated `n` times.

Comment: @concision I agree entirely; in fact, I reworked my answer based on your comment, as, upon reflection, my original answer was incorrect. Thank you for your suggestion!

Comment: Expanding off of recent edits, the lack of data locality can lead to poor performance when a memory page is not in the CPU cache and needs to be fetched from RAM. With individual node allocation, there is no guarantee of spatial locality in RAM - nodes may be in completely different pages. In lower level languages, this can be partially mitigated through memory pooling - pre-allocating blocks of memory where spatial locality is guaranteed and storing node data within the block. Furthermore, high level abstractions for trees can cause significant penalities in performance due to overhead.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend the **Heapsort** or **Mergesort**.

**Heapsort** is a comparison-based algorithm that uses a binary heap data structure to sort elements. It divides its input into a sorted and an unsorted region, and it iteratively shrinks the unsorted region by extracting the largest element and moving that to the sorted region.

**Mergesort** is a comparison-based algorithm that focuses on how to merge together two pre-sorted arrays such that the resulting array is also sorted.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this seems to be talking about sorting array, not keeping an array sorted as you construct it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a true `O(nlogn)` and sorted "as it is constructed", I would recommend using a proper (tree) based data structure instead of array. You can use data structures like [self balanced binary tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-balancing_binary_search_tree), [AVL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_tree) trees.

Answer (score 0):

**TimeSort**
Timsort is a hybrid sorting algorithm derived from merge sort and insertion sort. It was designed to perform well on many kinds of real-world data. Timsort was invented by Tim Peters in 2002 and is the default sorting algorithm in various programming languages and libraries, including Python.

The algorithm works by dividing the input array into small subarrays, which are individually sorted using insertion sort. Then, these sorted subarrays are merged together using a modified merge sort algorithm. The key idea behind Timsort is to take advantage of the existing order in the input data to minimize the number of comparisons and improve performance.

Here's a high-level overview of how Timsort works:

1. Divide the input array into small subarrays called "runs." A run is a sequence of elements that are already sorted or have a natural order.
2. Use insertion sort to sort each run individually. This step takes advantage of the fact that small arrays are often already partially sorted.
3. Merge the sorted runs together using a modified merge sort algorithm. The merge operation combines two runs into a larger, sorted run.
4. Repeat steps 1-3 until the entire array is sorted.

Timsort has several advantages over other sorting algorithms. It performs well on many kinds of data, including data with natural ordering or partially sorted data. It also has a stable sorting behavior, meaning that elements with equal values maintain their relative order in the sorted output. This property is particularly useful when sorting complex data structures that have multiple keys.

Overall, Timsort is a highly efficient and widely-used sorting algorithm known for its versatility and good performance characteristics in various scenarios.

The runtime complexity of Timsort is O(n log n) in the worst case, where "n" is the number of elements to be sorted. However, in practice, Timsort often exhibits better performance than other sorting algorithms, especially when dealing with real-world data.

The reason for the improved performance is that Timsort takes advantage of existing order in the input data. It identifies and merges already sorted subsequences (runs), reducing the number of comparisons needed during the merge step.

In the best-case scenario, where the input data is already sorted or has a significant amount of pre-existing order, Timsort can achieve a runtime complexity of O(n). This is because it can detect the sorted runs and simply perform the merging step without any additional sorting.

On average, Timsort performs better than other popular sorting algorithms, such as quicksort or merge sort, because it adapts its strategy based on the characteristics of the input data. It performs well on both small and large datasets and is particularly efficient when the data has partially sorted regions.

**Runtime**
It's worth noting that the actual runtime of Timsort can also be influenced by factors such as the hardware, programming language implementation, and specific optimizations applied to the algorithm. However, the worst-case and average-case time complexities mentioned above provide a general understanding of the performance characteristics of Timsort.